# compoment is not displaying

Tags: angular, typescript

i am working with angular lazy loading and not able to display the child1,child2, and child3 in main compoment.

here is the code for your referance

what i am trying to do is
display child1, child2 and child3 in main component which is in sharemodule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
--- app.component.html
<button routerLink="/home">home</button>
<button routerLink="/login">login</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false})],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [HomeComponent]
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

```
<h1>I am home</h1>
<a routerLink="/cust/features/child1">child1</a>
<a routerLink="/cust/features/child2">child2</a>
<a routerLink="/cust/features/child3">child3</a>
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from '../shared/main/main.component';

const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
      path: '', component: MainComponent,
      children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'cust', pathMatch: 'full'},
          { path: 'cust',
          loadChildren: () => import('../features/features.module').then(m => m.FeaturesModule)},
      ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'features' },
  { path: 'features', loadChildren: () =>
    import('./childrens/childrens.module').then((m) => m.ChildrensModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class FeaturesModule { }
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Child1Component } from './child1/child1.component';
import { Child2Component } from './child2/child2.component';
import { Child3Component } from './child3/child3.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'child1' },
  {path: 'child1', component: Child1Component},
  {path: 'child2', component: Child2Component},
  {path: 'child3', component: Child3Component},
  {path: '**', component: Child1Component},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Child1Component, Child2Component, Child3Component],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class ChildrensModule { }
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports: [MainComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

```
—main.html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html'
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```
--child1.html
<h1>i am child 1</h1>
```

```
--child2.html
<h1>i am child 2</h1>
```

```
--child3.html
<h1>i am child 3</h1>
```

I am trying very hard to fix it.
Any solution

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

remove `{ path: '**', component: HomeComponent }` from `AppRoutingModule` and see the magic happens.

---

When you define `path: '**'` it means every path except what I defined before!

By clicking on `childComponents` you are changing the path of `home` to `cust` and the `AppRouting` triggers the `path: **` then it rerender the home components and you stuck in a loop.

Comment: I think it's better to delete this question and update the last one!!!

Comment: when i removed that { path: '**', component: HomeComponent } from AppRoutingModule it worked but i am curious to know why

Comment: read the update

Comment: I'll appreciate it if you accept and upvote both answers.